# Prove functions are continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

$X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces and $f$ is a function from $x$ to $y$.

Prove that $f$ is continuous at $p$ if and only if f maps all sequences that converge to p to all sequences that converge to f(p)

Prove that $f$ is continuous if and only if the inverse images $f^{-1}(F)$ of all closed subsets of $F$ of $Y$ are closed subsets of $X$.

I don't know how to go about solving these, some really good intuitive hints would be cool, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f$ is continuous at $p$. Let $p_n$ be a sequence that converges to $p$. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Because $f$ is continuous, we may choose $\delta>0$ so that $d_X(p,q)<\delta$ implies $d_Y(f(p),f(q))<\varepsilon$. So choose $N$ so that $n\geqslant N$ implies $d_X(p,p_n)<\delta$. Then for $n\geqslant N$ we have $d_Y(f(p),f(p_n))<\varepsilon$, as desired.

The converse is similar.

Answer (score 0):

> Prove that $f$ is continuous if and only if the inverse images $f^{-1}(F)$ of all closed subsets $F$ of $Y$ are closed subsets of $X$.

If $F$ is closed then $F^c$ is open, and if $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed then $f^{-1}(F)^c=f^{-1}(F^c)$ is open.